# What sort of xml is the SimpleCursorAdapter expecting?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contacts, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I've been having problems with displaying Contacts in an AlertDialog, and I think I've found the 
problem, but am still confused. The pertinent suspect part of my code is:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mContacts,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

...Now "simple_list_item_1" is accepted by the compiler (the app runs in the Emulator), however when 
I try to run this ListActivity, it bombs.

So after reading elsewhere about how to accomplish this task my eyes lit upon the aforepasted 
"simple_list_item_1" - where is that? I didn't create any simple_list_item_1.xml file, and it doesn't exist in my \res\layout folder. So I (in Eclipse) right-clicked "simple_list_item_1" and selected "Open Declaration" and it invoked an err msg much or exactly like the one I see in the Debug Perspective about "Class File Editor | Source nout found | The JAR file ....\android.jar has no source attachment."

So...assuming this is the problem (there is no "simple_list_item_1.xml" in my \res\layout folder), what exactly is expected in this file (which I assume is simply a xml definition of what I want each Contact to display in)?

==============

Here is some LogCat data:

Here are the last lines in LogCat (it seems to die/hang once it gets to the ListActivity (ContactsActivity):

```
com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch/.KeepInTouchActivity: +5s368ms
01-08 21:54:34.020: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch/.ContactsActivity } from pid 385
```

...and here are all of the Error msgs in one attempted run (open the app, try to invoke the ListActivity). Note the "THIS SHOULD NEVER occur" msg at the end:

```
01-08 21:53:36.592: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
01-08 21:53:46.423: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
01-08 21:53:47.842: E/BatteryService(61): usbOnlinePath not found
01-08 21:53:47.842: E/BatteryService(61): batteryVoltagePath not found
01-08 21:53:47.842: E/BatteryService(61): batteryTemperaturePath not found
01-08 21:53:47.862: E/SurfaceFlinger(61): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
01-08 21:53:48.082: E/SensorService(61): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61): Failure starting core service
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
01-08 21:53:53.722: E/System(61):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:207)
01-08 21:53:53.742: E/EventHub(61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
01-08 21:53:53.742: E/EventHub(61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
01-08 21:53:54.032: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-08 21:53:54.032: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-08 21:53:54.032: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-08 21:53:54.042: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-08 21:53:54.042: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-08 21:53:54.703: E/ThrottleService(61): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
01-08 21:53:57.172: E/logwrapper(158): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-08 21:53:57.242: E/logwrapper(159): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-08 21:53:57.282: E/logwrapper(160): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-08 21:54:00.074: E/jdwp(174): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-08 21:54:00.712: E/Database(116): sqlite_config failed error_code = 21. THIS SHOULD NEVER occur.
```

Comment: error can occur if your cursor projection does not contain _ID column? is it present? Please post crash log

Comment: How to save crash log? I see a "save selected lines" option, but surely there's a way to save them all at once (Select All), but I don't see it...

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the _id column:

        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
...
            int selectedId = mContacts.getInt(0); // _ID column
...
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + selectedId, null, null);
...
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + selectedId, null, null);
...
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + selectedId, null, null);

Comment: click on any log line and press Ctrl+ A that should select all the log

Comment: OK, thanks; odd that isn't shown when right-clicking in LogCat.

Comment: I added LogCat data to the original message above.

Comment: I think you have posted wrong exception, If it is force close, search for fatal and post the stack below it.

Answer (score 2):

[simple_list_item_1](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) is a standard layout defined in the SDK, it's basically just a TextView with the id "android:id/text1", which is what you supply in your view identifiers.

Do you have the stacktrace of the crash? Because it's most likely not due to a missing simple_list_item_1 layout.

Comment: When I select "Export selected Items to Text File" nothing is exported (from LogCat); how do I do a "select all"?

Comment: Quite a bit of the "nitty gritty" is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767184/listactivity-starts-but-then-fails-almost-immediately

Answer (score 1):

Create a new XML layout file using Eclipse wizard. The name of this file will replace `simple_list_item_1` in your code:

In this layout, create a `TextView` (or any other container) element and call it `text1`:

Then `SimpleCursorAdaptor` will match your contact info and the `text1` field in your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Did it help solving your problem?